# Azure Function App in Python cannot see modules

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have Azure Function App in Python hosted in App Service Plan in Basic tier. I uploaded function from local VSCode to Azure Portal. Function is visible and enabled in Azure Portal. Then I installed Python venv in function root folder (using SSH in portal) and next I installed all dependencies related to this function. When function is running in Azure (trigger by TimeTrigger) it returns that particular module "is not found". What do I need to do to get this function to work properly?

The steps I took on the SSH side in the function container in Azure Portal:

1. Set up a Virtual Environment (venv):
   `python -m venv myenv`
2. Activate the Virtual Environment:
   `source myenv/bin/activate`
3. Install Dependencies in this venv:
   `pip install --target=<path-to-site-packages> -r requirements.txt`
4. Verify Dependencies:
   `pip list`

All steps above performed correctly, Python version is identical between local environment and venv, I restarted the function and unfortunately python modules imported in `__init__.py` are not visible / downloaded.

I described steps which I tried.
I expected to run function app correctly with all dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it and it was 2 issues:

1. Problem of Networking with Storage - I added VNet and special configuration to firewall and it works.
2. So problem was that in main python file I had "import asyncio" - it was a problem for Azure, because 'asyncio' is already built-in package in Python, so since this it returned error related to 'Module Not Found'

Answer (score 1):

- To achieve your requirement, create `requirements.txt` file with all the required python packages in *root folder of your project*.
- The `requirements.txt` is a simple text file which is used to specify the Python packages that are required by the Azure Function. When you deploy your Azure Function, the packages listed in the `requirements.txt` file are installed automatically in the function's environment.

---

I have created a simple python Azure function locally:

**Project Structure:**

[image]

**requirements.txt:**

I have used below packages in my project:

```py
azure-functions
numpy
pandas
```

**Code Snippet:**

```py
import datetime
import json
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully with {arr} and {df}.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

- Create and activate virtual environment, install the required packages:

[image]

**Running locally:**

[image]

[image]

- Created `Python Lunix Azure Function App with App Service Plan Basic tier`.

**Deployed my function to Azure Function App:**

[image]

- When you run the function, it activates *virtual environment* and install the dependencies which are mentioned in `requirements.txt`.

**Portal response:**

[image]

[image]